# How to parse eclipse plugin.xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plug-in project in my eclipse workspace, that is imported in antoher plug-in project. I need to access the extension points of the imported project.  Because both plug-ins are in the workspace, I can't use the `ExtensionRegistry`. Is there a simple way to parse the `plugin.xml`?

edit: I tried now to create an `IExtensionRegistry` and add the `plugin.xml` (Xtend code)

```
    val registry = RegistryFactory.createRegistry(null, "master", "user")

    val projects = ResourcesPlugin.workspace.root.projects
    for (project : projects.filter[findMember("plugin.xml") !== null]) {
        val pluginXml = project.findMember("plugin.xml")
        val pluginXmlUri = URI.createFileURI(pluginXml.locationURI.path)
        try {
            val pluginXmlStream = URIConverter.INSTANCE.createInputStream(pluginXmlUri)
            val contributor = ContributorFactorySimple.createContributor(project.name)
            registry.addContribution(pluginXmlStream, contributor, false, project.name, null, "master")
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // ignore this plugin.xml
        }
    }
```

`addContribution` returns true, but `registry` has no extension or extension point after the loop. Is there any further configuration necessary?

Comment: When you run your plugin (using 'Run As > Eclipse Application') it will be installed in a test version of Eclipse along with the other plugin - so you can use the extension point registry.

Comment: @greg-449 this doesn't work for me. The imported and importing projects are plug-in projects created by the user, I want to access the plugin.xml of the imported project in the builder of the importing project (I'm writing the builder).

Comment: So you are trying to import a project in to an installation yourself? The Eclipse p2 install code is usually used for things like that. I don't know of any public API for reading the plugin.xml. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and explain in more detail why you need to do this.

Comment: You might want to look at the code in `org.eclipse.emf.ecore.plugin.EcorePlugin.ExtensionProcessor` which seems to be doing something similar.